# trying to get the max of a column in sql while referencing different tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, procedure

I have a question about how would I access the max value for gradterm within my SQL code? Here is an example of my plain code:

```
SELECT 
    Ceremony.Date, People.name, People.age
FROM 
    people
JOIN 
    Ceremony ON people.grad = Ceremony.grad
```

As you can see I am using the grad column of both tables to display the date of the `Ceremony` table based on what the grad is in the `people` table. Here is what I thought would work for getting the max grad values:

```
SELECT 
    Ceremony.Date, people.name, people.age
FROM 
    people
JOIN 
    Ceremony ON MAX(people.grad) = MAX(Ceremony.grad)
```

I get this error when I try to execute it:

> An aggregate cannot appear in an ON clause unless it is in a subquery in a HAVING
>   clause or select list, and the column being aggregated in an outer reference.

I did try doing the `Ceremony.Date` with the `MAX` function, but that didn't work. Also here is an example of what the table looks like:

`people` table:

```
    |name|age|gradterm|
    -------------------
    |jake|20 |A       |
    |joe |23 |B       |
```

`Ceremony` table:

```
    |Date     |gradterm|
    --------------------
    |Dec 21   |   A    |
    |Fall 21  |   B    |
```

When the `gradterm` in the people table "A" then the GridView I am using to display my SQL data (through a stored procedure) would display "Dec 21" as the `Ceremony` date. Also for gradterm in the peoples table to be "B", the gridview would display "Fall 21". All I am wanting it to get the max gradterm when comparing it to get the ceremony date. I thank everyone in advance for their help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need to group by the other fields before you can do aggregation

```
SELECT c.Date, People.name, People.age, c.GradTerm
FROM people
INNER JOIN (SELECT Date, MAX(grad) [GradTerm]
            FROM Ceremony
            GROUP BY Date) c
    ON people.grad = c.grad
```